# TypeError: 'stepUp' called on an object that does not implement interface HTMLInputElement in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-post

I am calling the php file using jquery $.post method.At the time of the retriving the data I am getting an error.

I did search on google,found 4 to 5 solutions but those are not working.

Please help me.

this is my code,

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

 $("[name='side_door_on_size']").click(function (){
        var side_door_on_size=$(this).val();
        $.post('<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/thermax/filter.php',
               {side_door_on_size:side_door_on_size}, 
               function(data){
                  alert(data);
              });
       })
  })
```

**Html**

```
<input type="radio" name="side_door_on_size" class="side_door_on_size" id="side_door_on_size" value="25m"/>25m
```

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Please add element name in jQuery selector `$("input[name=side_door_on_size]")`,

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $("input[name=side_door_on_size]").click(function (){
        var side_door_on_size=$(this).val();
        $.post('<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/thermax/filter.php',
               {side_door_on_size:side_door_on_size}, 
               function(data){
                  alert(data);
              });
       })
  })
```

Comment: thank you for your quick replay,i tried with your code but it is not working

Answer (score -2):

please try with

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("[name=side_door_on_size]").click(function() {
            var side_door_on_size = $(this).val();
            $.post('<?php echo get_home_url(); ?>/wp-content/plugins/thermax/filter.php', {side_door_on_size: side_door_on_size}, function(data) {
                alert(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```